# Resizing height based on other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation that looks like this:

[image]

Basically a section, and under the section, I have 3 columns/panels. Depending on data stored in any of those columns it sometimes looks a bit empty. It also gets complicated when there are 3 columns + 3 columns below (currently shown 2), because if that happens and there is no data on 3rd column everything will move up to the 1st row. I tried to set static height and it worked but at the same time when you press + sign it expands.. and that stops working.

Is there a way to resize height based on the longest element?

Relevant part of css:

```
        div.defaultSection {
            border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            /* display: inline-block; */
            margin: 5px;
            width: calc(100% - 10px);
            overflow: hidden;
            /* NEW */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
        }
        div.defaultColumn {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* NEW */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        .defaultCard {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
```

Full code for that page is here: https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/blob/master/Examples/Example14-Other/Example14.html

Comment: which class you need to set the height?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian             `<div class="defaultColumn defaultCard" style="width: calc(100% / 3 - 10px); ;">` is the one responsible for one of those 3. So i guess defaultcolumn

Comment: Have you tried getting the height of the element by jquery then assign it to defaultcolumn?

Comment: I did not. My knowledge on HTML/JS/CSS is limited. I'm skilled in PowerShell and this project basically generates HTML/JS/CSS using PowerShell. When I have to use CSS/HTML I just sit down and see what things do when I do them. With Jquery it's a bit problematic because I have no knowledge of it. I can fix simple things, but not anything as complicated as this.

Comment: I wish I would have a guy that know HTML/CSS/JS for this open source project so I could focus on PowerShell generation. Instead I'm fighting things  I have no clue about ;-)

Comment: I'll post something as answer I dont know if  it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Flexbox instead of floats... The content in the row will always be the same height as the tallest item and won't wrap unless you specify that it should.

CSS Tricks has a very good [flexbox overview](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

But here's an example to get you started:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background-color: #5C8ADE;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Short Content</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum egestas nisi quis consequat. Aenean sit amet ligula massa. Morbi ut aliquet mauris. Nullam eget ipsum et magna luctus rhoncus. Curabitur aliquet erat non erat iaculis, vitae aliquet mi malesuada. Mauris tempus enim sed ligula molestie, nec efficitur dui volutpat. Maecenas euismod sed nisl sed ultricies. Duis gravida sem ac tellus consectetur blandit. Sed nec metus non augue facilisis malesuada in quis orci. Suspendisse blandit, augue at ullamcorper pulvinar, massa elit lacinia odio, tempus accumsan libero ex eu leo.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've looked a while back into flexbox and it was a bit problematic for me as it was misbehaving (comparing to my current behavior). I may need to give it another look.

Comment: @MadBoy yes Flexbox is a different way of thinking. But I feel like you'll end up fighting with how `floats` want to work compared to your desired result.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I had to change things around but generally, it gave me a few more options.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need but add this to your html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var highest = $(".defaultCard").offset().top + $(".defaultCard").height();
        $(".defaultColumn").height(highest); // or if didn't work
        document.getElementByClassName("defaultColumn").style.height = highest; // then try this
        // make sure only use one of two lines above
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this won't really work. I have lots of default column classes added and it will track all of them. I guess I would need to do ID per row and based on that play with your code. Thank you for an effort thou. If I will have to go back to this I'll use this. I'll try using flexbox first.

Comment: No problem. Just remember if you use id use getElementbyId instead of getElementByClassName